# Rails 3, only rendering partial if a user is logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, devise

On a Rails 3.1 app, I have a method called `user_logged_in?` from Devise, which I want to use to render a partial selectively. Here's the code in layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<% if user_logged_in? %>
<%= render :partial => "home/statusbar" %>
<% end %>
```

It uses a partial from a different controller. This is the partial:

```
<div id="status_bar">  
  Signed in as <%= link_to current_user.name, edit_user_registration_path %>
</div>
```

An error occurs at `current_user.name` (undefined method), because `current_user` is `nil`. I could move the `user_logged_in?` check inside the partial, but I think it would be marginally more efficient if it were in the view.

Could you direct me to what the best practices are, or how I can overcome the undefined method error? Is it normal that Rails checks the code of the template even though it's in an `if` block that fails?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like `user_logged_in?` is where something is going wrong.Does it work if you change to this?

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
  <%= render :partial => "home/statusbar" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, it does. It also works if I use user_signed_in?. Totally wrong method. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm familiar with Devise, but not the `user_logged_in?` method - did you define it yourself?  The normal helper used in views is `user_signed_in?`. Also, try something like the following:

```
<% puts user_logged_in?.inspect %>
<% puts user_signed_in?.inspect %>
```

Above the if statement in your view, and check your logs to make sure your call is returning `false` correctly (`user_signed_in?` should also be returning `false`).  You should not be getting a nil error in that partial unless it is actually being rendered (meaning the code entered the if statement).

Answer (score 1):

That code is being run, ruby is duck typed and dynamic, all checks are at runtime. So you need to check your conditional . Try

```
<% if false %>
  <%= render :partial => "home/statusbar" %>
<% end %>
```

and see if it stll fails.
A bettter solution would be

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= render :partial => "home/statusbar" %>
<% end %>
```

I am unfamiliar with devise but this should work 
Since current user wil be nil if nobody is logged in

Comment: You're right, I was supposed to use user_signed_in, not user_logged_in! Thanks for the informative answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it appears that

```
user_logged_in?
```

Is not used anymore, and instead you need to use

```
user_signed_in?
```

So with the code you gave this should work:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= render :partial => "home/statusbar" %>
<% end %>
```

This code rendered a partial for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an even shorter way to render your partial with a conditional

```
<%= render(partial: "home/statusbar") if current_user.present? %>
```